# Spark.sql select rows that do not have matching column in other table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe called edges which looks like:

```
+------+------+-------------------+                                             
|   src|   dst|      mean_affinity|
+------+------+-------------------+
|  [78]|  [81]|   0.78547141736462|
|  [98]| [102]| 0.8051602291309927|
|[2540]|[3195]| 0.7734367678994718|
|   [1]|[1367]|0.37372281429944215|
| [182]|[1602]| 0.3915882096267663|
|   [1]|  [77]| 0.6999457255005836|
|  [55]|  [78]| 0.4411667943000793|
+------+------+-------------------+
```

I don't want any repeated in src and dst column.
For example 78 is src in the first row, so it cannot be as a dst in the last row. In other words, any vertex can only appears one in the table.

Also the table should be sorted by mean_affinity.
I started writing a query for this, but it doesn't seems to work:

```
sqlContext.sql("""select e.src, e.dst, e.mean_affinity 
                    from edges e
                    where not exists 
                   (select src from edges where src = e.dst)""").show()
```

this is part of the stacktrace:

```
 An error occurred while calling o111.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [3.46] failure: ``)'' expected but identifier src found

                    where not exists (select src from edges where src = e.dst)
                                             ^
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Thanks!

Comment: BTW are you using python or scala?

Comment: This issue seems to be tracked at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4226 and some work is in progress (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12610) to add the missing parts to Spark SQL.